# Cassandra health check in phantom

Tags: scala, cassandra, health-monitoring, kubernetes-health-check, phantom-dsl

In our containerised scala application , we are using phantom library for persisting and retrieving data from `Cassandra`. We have a requirement to do regular health check on Cassandra.

Presently, on bootstrap of application when there is a deployment in any new kubernetes pod, we check for an active Cassandra session and then later run a scheduled check on Cassandra health.

Appreciate if could share alternatives to do health check on Cassandra.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using the **[DataStax Cassandra Operator](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cass-operator/doc/cass-operator/cassOperatorTOC.html)** (**cass-operator**), the health check is already done for you automatically. If a pod goes down, the cass-operator will automatically attempt to recover it for you.

If you haven't already seen it, have a look at open-source [**K8ssandra**](https://k8ssandra.io/). It is a ready-made platform for running Apache Cassandra in Kubernetes using the DataStax Cassandra Operator under the hood but with all the tooling built-in:

- **[Reaper](http://cassandra-reaper.io/docs/)** for automated repairs
- **[Medusa](https://github.com/thelastpickle/cassandra-medusa/wiki)** for backups and restores
- [**Metrics Collector**](https://github.com/datastax/metric-collector-for-apache-cassandra) for monitoring with Prometheus + Grafana
- Traefik templates for k8s cluster ingress

Since all these components are open-source, they are all free to use and don't require a licence or paid subscription but still comes with a robust community support. Cheers!